Use "The demand for English learning" or “the demand for learning English"?

the demand for English learning


the demand for learning English

These two phrases have the same meaning, but I feel that the first one is more formally used than the latter one.
Is it right? And if it is, in which circumstances do we use these phrases?
The same question applies to any two phrases which have the form: “the demand for Ving + N” and “the demand for N + Ving”

There's no demand for "English learning" or for "learning English".  There may be a demand for people who can speak English, who have learned English. What do you mean by it? Demand for English teachers by those who wish to learn English?

Your These two phrases have the same meaning is an unqualified assertion. In one sense it is true, since they are both non-idiomatic, as @TimR has commented. Perhaps the demand for English instruction? But this one is a bit ambiguous, interpretable as referring either to instruction about or instruction delivered in English.

I mean there are so many students who want to learn English in my area. @PaulTanenbaum

I reiterate @TimR’s point: When it’s used in this more or-less economic sense, the phrase  demand for typically takes as its complement a good or service, and instruction—whether in physics, swimming, English, or whatever—is such a service. By contrast, learning is not a service, but the result of receiving the service (of instruction).

So what about the sentence @Lambie provided? If “English learning” is not a service, why is “English language learning” a service? By your explanation, it seems to me that “English (language) teaching” is the only option here.

Yes, I find the usage in @lambie’s answer to be somewhat off. But this is an opinion, which is why I made it a comment rather than an answer. In any event, English learning is definitely not a service: how much would you be willing to pay someone to cause them to learn English, and how would their learning it constitute doing you a service?

I'd suggest adding the rest of the imaginary sentence. You explained more in a comment, but comments aren't an official or permanent part of the question.

The market is: the English language learning market [google it]. Where there is a market, there is a demand for goods or services, as they say in economics. So, the demand for English language learning is completely accurate.


In the post-Brexit landscape of the European Union (EU) by 2025, the
demand for English language learning is set to undergo major shifts.
high demand for English
Research shows the projected growth of the English language learning
market could reach nearly $70 billion by 2029. A large portion of the
market is made up of Business English instruction.  English language
learning

So, the proper term is: English language learning and not just: learning English.

Thank you. I mean there are so many students who want to learn English in my area. As far as I understand as of now, there are some ways to say it:  "the demand for English language learning is high" (your suggestion), "the demand for English teaching is high", "the demand for English language teaching is high". What is wrong among these and what is the most natural way to say it?

@Phoebe All those are fine. Demand for English language teaching is not the same as demand for English language learning. One is teaching (the teachers available) and the other is learning (those who want to learn).

So, is “the demand for English language learning” is something of a school? (Because the schools want to have more students who want to learn English). And “the demand for English Language teaching” is something of a student (the students want to have more teaching services)?

Phoebe: Please make an effort. What is demand in economics? Here, it would come from English language schools (of any type): they can be interested in knowing the number of teachers and students there is demand for.

I feel like the question has been muddied by the fact that there are better words for this idea. But the question "how do I turn a verb and object into a single noun phrase?" is worth answering. Let's use some different examples.

I like to carve wood.
I'm looking for someone who can teach me to juggle fire.

How do we turn these verbs and objects into noun phrases? We could put the verb first, but it's more common to put the object first. This is especially true when the activity is a common one that people recognize and talk about often.

I like wood carving.
I'm looking for a fire juggling teacher.

If the activity is very unusual, it might be better to put the verb first as usual, and not even try to turn it into a noun phrase:

There's been a high demand for painting trees pink. For some reason.


There is the phrase book-learning which refers to the kind of education, the sort of knowledge, one receives by reading, typically  contrasted with the hands-on learning one gets by doing things either alone or under the supervision of a mentor.  It's possible to use "English learning" in a similar fashion, as a synonym for "English knowledge" or "knowledge of English", but it sounds somewhat old-fashioned and quaint, especially when used in the context of international trade and economic demand.

There is nowadays a demand for English reading and speaking skills, as English has become the de facto language of international trade.  Many students around the world want to learn the language, and so there is also a demand for qualified English teachers.

